# Change URL dynamically depending on datepicker's value angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<label>From</label>
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="StartDate"/>
<label>To</label>
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="EndDate"/>
```

The URL route is :

`GET    /admin/api/stats                                            controllers.AdminStatsApi.get(start: Option[LocalDate], end: Option[LocalDate], computeDiff: Boolean ?= false)`

My question is how can I change the URL depending on the date (value) entered in the `datepicker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given insufficient information. What do you use? ui-router? $location?

But basically you can do something like that:

```
var changeUrl = function(startDate, endDate){
  //do url change with whatever thing you are using to change your url
}

$scope.$watch('StartDate', function(newValue){
   var start = newValue;
   var end = $scope.endDate;

   //do your url change here
   changeUrl(start, end);
}, true);


$scope.$watch('EndDate', function(newValue){
   var start = $scope.startDate;
   var end = newValue;

   //do your url change here
   changeUrl(start, end);
}, true);
```